# Velocity verlet algorithm java

Tags: java, algorithm

How important is the size of the time step in the velocity verlet algorithm? I'm using it in a simulation, and it is WAY out for large time steps (about 1000 seconds, say), but really close for small ones e.g. 2 seconds. Is this an instability in some other area of my code or from the algorithm?

Without actually seeing the code I appreciate that no answer will be definite, but essentially, should I expect large error with large time steps in velocity verlet?

Large means a few orders of magnitude out, to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity Verlet, as all variants of the Verlet-Stoermer class (if correctly implemented, esp. in the first step) has error order 2. Which means that changing the time step from 2s to 1000s can increase the error by a factor of 250000. Provided there are no events of the scale of duration less or about 500s in the trajectory, because that would destroy the assumptions of the error estimate.